# How do you return a value properly?

Tags: c#, function

I'm working on a application that allows the user to track a money saving goal.

```
public static int CalcProg(int userGoal, int userBalance, int userProg)
{
    userProg = userBalance / userGoal;
    userProg = userProg * 100
    return userProg;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Calls the FileVerification Method
    FileVerification();

    //Sets the label1 transparency to true
    label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
    label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    LoadData();
    CalcProg(userGoal, userBalance, userProg);

    progressBar1.Value = userProg;
    progLabel = Convert.ToString(userProg);
    label3.Text = progLabel;
}
```

This is just a small section of the code, but it's where I'm having problems.

I use methods to read and write a file for data used in the variables userBalance, and userGoal. This is all working fine, because when I use one of those variables instead of "userProg" in the convert function below, it shows up just as it is in the text file.

My problem comes when I try to do the conversion. My formula is in CalcProg. When I when I actually start up the program, two elements (a progress bar, and a label) that set their value on the variable userProg, just display zero no matter what value is entered in the text file.

I've tried using a double for the CalcProg method and setting userProg as a double, but that doesn't work. I'm a little stuck, and would appreciate some help if someone can help me.

Comment: Can you show us your `LoadData` method?

Comment: You haven't assigned the value returned by `CalcProg` to a variable.

Comment: you probably need to set a few break points and step into your program and pinpoint the root cause. and your CalcProg method looks rather wired - why did you pass in userProg while use it like a local varialbe and the passed-in value is never been used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem is, you are returning an int from your method, but you never use it.
Change your code to:

```
public static int CalcProg(int userGoal, int userBalance, int userProg)
{
    userProg = userBalance / userGoal;
    userProg = userProg * 100
    return userProg;

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Calls the FileVerification Method
    FileVerification();
    //Sets the label1 transparency to true
    label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
    label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    LoadData();

    progressBar1.Value = CalcProg(userGoal, userBalance, userProg);
    progLabel = Convert.ToString(userProg);
    label3.Text = progLabel;


}
```

Comment: Nice catch. Completely missed that.

Comment: In other words, the output of the method 'CalcProg' is not being used as input for anything else :)

Comment: Or, the method `CalcProg`is useless in the way it is used.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. In other languages that i've used before, I've never had to use this method of accessing a value from a function, and I wasn't aware this is how it worked in C#.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change the save parameter you pass to method and use that after you call the method, then you can simply change the parameter as `out` parameter

You can call the method as

```
 CalcProg(userGoal, userBalance, out userProg);
```

And the method

```
public static void CalcProg(int userGoal, int userBalance, out int userProg)
{
    userProg = userBalance / userGoal;
    userProg = userProg * 100;
}
```